Why is EF looking for a column that doesn't exist?
Everything compiles, but at runtime I get
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException     
  HResult=0x80131904     
  Message=Invalid column name 'DeviceModelID'.     
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider     
  StackTrace:     
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    

There is no DeviceModelID in the database or in my code.
I'm not sure why it's looking for it.
The DeviceModel has an ID called ID.
Here's the offending code:
public void LoadComponents(IDeviceSummaryContext context) {
    List<ComponentModel> components = 
        context.Components                      |
        .Join(context.DevicesComponents,        |
           c => c.ID,                           |
           dc => dc.ComponentID,                | -- Error here
           (c, dc) => new { c, dc })            |
        .Where(x => x.dc.DeviceID == DeviceID)  |
        .Select(x => x.c).ToList();             |
    foreach(var item in components) {
        Components.Add(item);
    }
}

Called from here, so you can see where DeviceID comes from:
private static DeviceSummaryModel InternalDeviceSummary(IDeviceSummaryContext deviceSummaryContext, QRModel qr, DeviceModel device) {
    DeviceSummaryModel model = new DeviceSummaryModel {
        QRKey = qr.QRKey,
        DeviceID = device.ID,
        TagNumber = device.TagNumber
    };
    model.LoadComponents(deviceSummaryContext);
    return model;
}

The model for the join table:
[PrimaryKey(nameof(ComponentID), nameof(DeviceID))]
public class DevicesComponentsModel {
    //[Key]
    //[Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Components")]
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }

    //[Key]
    //[Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("Devices")]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
}

The context:
public interface IDeviceSummaryContext {
    public DbSet<ComponentModel> Components { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeviceModel> Devices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DevicesComponentsModel> DevicesComponents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MasterModel> MasterDocs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QRModel> QRKeys { get; set; }

}

Device Model. ComponentModel is similar:
[PrimaryKey(nameof(ID))]  // I tried adding this, but it didn't help.
public class DeviceModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TagNumber { get; set; } = "";
    public string QRKey { get; set; } = "";
    public int? DocID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }       
    public ICollection<ComponentModel> Components { get; set; } = [];        
}

The query it is trying to run is
DECLARE @__DeviceID_0 int = 2;

SELECT [c].[ID], [c].[DeviceModelID], [c].[Model], [c].[Type], [c].[Vendor]
FROM [Components] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [DevicesComponents] AS [d] ON [c].[ID] = [d].[ComponentID]
WHERE [d].[DeviceID] = @__DeviceID_0


ForeignKey("Components") - is there any reason why you have not exposed the navigation properties?

Also highly likely you can do Components.AddRange(components) instead of iterating and adding them by one. And consider using async  versions of materialization methods (i.e. ToListAsync etc.)

@Progman I added the generated query

Can you please add a full runnable [mre]? Or at least all relevant entities declarations

You most likely forgot to apply a migration. Add a migration via dotnet ef migration add <somename> and see what it contains, usually gives you a hint what you changed in your model. Also, why are you creating a cross table on your own? EF Core 5.0 and newer already support many-to-many navigation properties, so a model for the cross table isn't required anymore (EF Core will create the cross table implicitly when creating the migration)

Either that, or you have misconfigured the navigations, i.e. you set up navigation on a non-existing column/relations. Best to start over and use navigation properties and skip the cross table. It also helps to apply the C# naming conventions ID -> Id. EF Core's conventions won't recognize IDor DeviceID as a foreign key of Device model as it's against the C# conventions (In C# you never write ALL-CAPS or more than 1 uppercase letter, except for interfaces (IMyClass) and 2-character names such as IO -> IOException

In your ComponentModel, navigate whether the entity points to the Device?After testing, if you navigate to a ComponentModel entity, then efcore will generate a new column DeviceModelID when migrating :


Solution Example:
DevicesComponentsModel :
[PrimaryKey(nameof(ComponentID), nameof(DeviceID))]
public class DevicesComponentsModel
{  
    [ForeignKey("Components")]
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }
       
    [ForeignKey("Devices")]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public DeviceModel Device { get; set; }
    public ComponentModel Component { get; set; }
}

Configure navigation with DeviceModel in ComponentModel class:
public ICollection<DeviceModel> Devices { get; set; } = new List<DeviceModel>();

Result query:

